# API resolved without sending a response for /api/products, this may result in stalled requests. (How can i make a get operation)?

Tags: api, next.js, crud

```
import dbConnect from '../../../utils/mongo'
import Product from '../../../models/Product'

export default async function handler(req, res) {
   const {method} =req;
   
   
   dbConnect();
   
   
   if(method ==="GET"){
    try{                            
        const products = await Product.find();
        res.status(200).json(products);
    }
    catch(err){
       res.status(500).json(err);
    }
   }


   if(method ==="POST"){
    try{                                  
        const product = await Product.create(req.body);
        res.status(201).json(product); 
   
    }
    catch(err){
        res.status(500).json(err);
    }
   }

  }
```

So here I want to use res.status(200).json(products); to perform the get operation,
however, I'm receiving the error:

> API resolved without sending a response for /api/products, this may result in stalled requests

When trying to run the get request with postman or axios, however post request works just fine. Any suggestions to solve it would be welcome

Answer (score 3):

For anyone still looking for a solution for this, export this from the api route, you can just add the following code to your endpoint and it should resolve that :

```js
export const config = {
  api: {
    externalResolver: true,
  },
}
```

note that this will disable the warning!

Comment: Wow, the only answer that helped in my case. Thank you!